# Zoom meeting link in firefox launches Zoom but does not connect to meeting

Tags: firefox, zoom-meeting

If I open a Zoom meeting link in Google Chrome, the Zoom app launches and the meeting is opened. If I do the same in Firefox, the Zoom app opens, but the meeting is not connected. How do get Firefox to send the right info to the app so that the meeting is opened?